# C++ callback timer implementation

Tags: c++, multithreading, timer, pthreads

I have found the following implementation for a callback timer to use in my c++ application. However, this implementation requires me to "join" the thread from the `start` caller, which effectively blocks the caller of the start function.

What I really like to do is the following.

1. someone can call foo(data) multiple times and store them in a db.
2. whenever foo(data) is called, it initiates a timer for few seconds.
3. while the timer is counting down, foo(data) can be called several
   times and multiple items can be stored, but doesn't call erase until timer finishes
4. whenever the timer is up,
   the "remove" function is called once to remove all the records from the
   db.

Bascially I want to be able to do a task, and wait a few seconds and batch do a single batch task B after a few seconds.

```
class CallBackTimer {

public:

    /**
     * Constructor of the CallBackTimer
     */
    CallBackTimer() :_execute(false) { }

    /**
     * Destructor
     */
    ~CallBackTimer() {
        if (_execute.load(std::memory_order_acquire)) {
            stop();
        };
    }

    /**
     * Stops the timer
     */
    void stop() {
        _execute.store(false, std::memory_order_release);
        if (_thd.joinable()) {
            _thd.join();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Start the timer function
     * @param interval Repeating duration in milliseconds, 0 indicates the @func will run only once
     * @param delay Time in milliseconds to wait before the first callback
     * @param func Callback function
     */
    void start(int interval, int delay, std::function<void(void)> func) {
        if(_execute.load(std::memory_order_acquire)) {
            stop();
        };
        _execute.store(true, std::memory_order_release);


        _thd = std::thread([this, interval, delay, func]() {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(delay));
            if (interval == 0) {
                func();
                stop();
            } else {
                while (_execute.load(std::memory_order_acquire)) {
                    func();
                    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(interval));
                }
            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * Check if the timer is currently running
     * @return bool, true if timer is running, false otherwise.
     */
    bool is_running() const noexcept {
        return ( _execute.load(std::memory_order_acquire) && _thd.joinable() );
    }


private:
    std::atomic<bool> _execute;
    std::thread _thd;

};
```

I have tried modifying the above code using the thread.detach(). However, I am running issues in detached thread not being able to write (erase) from the database..

Any help and suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: Could you add a sample of how you are using this class? What you are asking for seems risky and unnecessary.

Comment: Maybe you can construct the thread in constructor and join it in destructor? Then you only need a std::queue to add new items(callbacks) into by start() and flush all elements by stop(). Once it goes out of scope, destructor will take care of thread. Then there would be a while loop in thread, yields until queue has any item. Then starts processing it. Next while loop would check both timer and number of items. Inside, it would process items 1 by 1. Then let it repeat until stopped. Destructor will do the cleaning. I guess interval is waiting between items and delay is just its trigger time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than using threads you could use `std::async`. The following class will process the queued strings in order 4 seconds after the last string is added. Only 1 async task will be launched at a time and `std::aysnc` takes care of all the threading for you.

If there are unprocessed items in the queue when the class is destructed then the async task stops without waiting and these items aren't processed (but this would be easy to change if its not your desired behaviour).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <future>
#include <mutex>
#include <chrono>
#include <queue>

class Batcher
{
public:
  Batcher()
    : taskDelay( 4 ),
      startTime( std::chrono::steady_clock::now() ) // only used for debugging
  {
  }

  void queue( const std::string& value )
  {
    std::unique_lock< std::mutex > lock( mutex );
    std::cout << "queuing '" << value << " at " << std::chrono::duration_cast< std::chrono::milliseconds >( std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - startTime ).count() << "ms\n";
    work.push( value );
    // increase the time to process the queue to "now + 4 seconds"
    timeout = std::chrono::steady_clock::now() + taskDelay;
    if ( !running )
    {
      // launch a new asynchronous task which will process the queue
      task = std::async( std::launch::async, [this]{ processWork(); } );
      running = true;
    }
  }

  ~Batcher()
  {
    std::unique_lock< std::mutex > lock( mutex );
    // stop processing the queue
    closing = true;
    bool wasRunning = running;
    condition.notify_all();
    lock.unlock();
    if ( wasRunning )
    {
      // wait for the async task to complete
      task.wait();
    }
  }

private:
  std::mutex mutex;
  std::condition_variable condition;
  std::chrono::seconds taskDelay;
  std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point timeout;
  std::queue< std::string > work;
  std::future< void > task;
  bool closing = false;
  bool running = false;
  std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point startTime;

  void processWork()
  {
    std::unique_lock< std::mutex > lock( mutex );
    // loop until std::chrono::steady_clock::now() > timeout
    auto wait = timeout - std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    while ( !closing && wait > std::chrono::seconds( 0 ) )
    {
      condition.wait_for( lock, wait );
      wait = timeout - std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    }
    if ( !closing )
    {
      std::cout << "processing queue at " << std::chrono::duration_cast< std::chrono::milliseconds >( std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - startTime ).count() << "ms\n";
      while ( !work.empty() )
      {
        std::cout << work.front() << "\n";
        work.pop();
      }
      std::cout << std::flush;
    }
    else
    {
      std::cout << "aborting queue processing at " << std::chrono::duration_cast< std::chrono::milliseconds >( std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - startTime ).count() << "ms with " << work.size() << " remaining items\n";
    }
    running = false;
  }
};

int main()
{
  Batcher batcher;
  batcher.queue( "test 1" );
  std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::seconds( 1 ) );
  batcher.queue( "test 2" );
  std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::seconds( 1 ) );
  batcher.queue( "test 3" );
  std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::seconds( 2 ) );
  batcher.queue( "test 4" );
  std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::seconds( 5 ) );
  batcher.queue( "test 5" );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, actually I found the underlying problem is not because of the CallbackTimer / Batcher. For some reason, the sqlite statement from the callback (in your case, the `auto function = work.front() && function()` that deletes the row from the table gets executed, but not actually deleting the row.